# setting activerecord attribute based on virtual attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, attributes

i have an attribute called `dimensions` which i want to set based on my `width`, `height`, and `depth` attributes.

for example, i want to do `ShippingProfile.find(1).width = 4`, and have it save to dimensions as {:width => 4, :height => 0, :depth => 0}`

is this possible?

```
class ShippingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_default_dimensions

  serialize :dimensions, Hash

  attr_accessor :width, :height, :depth
  attr_accessible :width, :height, :depth, :dimensions

  private

    def set_default_dimensions
      self.dimensions ||= {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}
    end  
end
```

Comment: Don't you think ShippingProfile.find(1).dimensions.width = 4 would be better ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Very much so, all you need to do is use a callback to set the value of self.dimensions:

```
class ShippingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :set_default_dimensions
  after_validation :set_dimensions

  serialize :dimensions, Hash

  attr_accessor :width, :height, :depth
  attr_accessible :width, :height, :depth, :dimensions

  private

  def set_default_dimensions
    self.dimensions ||= {:width => 0, :height => 0, :depth => 0}
  end

  def set_dimensions
    self.dimensions = { 
      :width  => self.width || self.dimensions[:width],
      :height => self.height || self.dimensions[:height],
      :depth  => self.depth || self.dimensions[:depth],
    }
  end
end
```

You need to use `self.foo || self.dimensions[:foo]` to ensure that you preserve any existing values already set in the hash. Why? Your dimension attributes (I'm assuming) aren't being persisted in the database - you're using attr_accessor, rather than setting them up as fields in your table.

As an aside, I think you're going about your model design the wrong way. By storing the dimensions as a hash in the database, not only do you lose the ability to query based on those attributes, but you add a level of fragility you don't need.

If you *are* storing your individual dimension attributes as separate fields, then you're introducing redundancy and complexity. You would be better served by having the three attributes as fields in your database (if you aren't already), then generating the dimensions hash on the fly when it's needed:

```
class ShippingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  def dimensions
    { :width => self.width, :height => self.height, :depth => self.depth }
  end
end
```

This way, you retain the functionality and gain some flexibility.

Comment: so i went with storing the individual dimensions. it was far less problematic and like you said, much more flexible with querying.  sometimes i get caught up with keeping a nice looking DB, but the reality of it is, i never have to really look at it :)

Answer (score 0):

```
ShippingProfile.find(1).dimensions[:width] = 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class in serialize, so

```
class ShippingProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :dimensions, Dimensions
end

class Dimensions
  attr_accessor :width, :height,:depth

  def initialize
    @width = 0
    @height = 0
    @depth = 0
  end

  def volume
    width * height * depth
  end
end
```

Now you can do ShippingProfile.dimensions.width = 1 and later ShippingProfile.dimension.volume etc..

A model would be a richer representation than a Hash